# Show top N scores in MySQL 8 without duplicates by category

Tags: mysql, group-by, mysql-8.0

I have the following table in MySQL 8.0.15:

```
CREATE TABLE golf_scores (person TEXT, score INT);
INSERT INTO golf_scores VALUES ('Angela', 40),('Angela', 45),('Angela', 55),('Peter',45),('Peter',55),('Rachel', 65),('Rachel',75),('Jeff',75);

SELECT * FROM golf_scores;
+--------+-------+
| person | score |
+--------+-------+
| Angela |    40 |
| Angela |    45 |
| Angela |    55 |
| Peter  |    45 |
| Peter  |    55 |
| Rachel |    65 |
| Rachel |    75 |
| Jeff   |    75 |
+--------+-------+
```

I am trying to get the following top 3 scores:

```
SELECT * FROM golf_scores;
+--------+-------+
| person | score |
+--------+-------+
| Angela |    40 |
| Peter  |    45 |
| Rachel |    65 |
+--------+-------+
```

In other words, I want the best (lowest) 3 golf score without having duplicates by person.  I'm not worried about ties; I'd still just like three results.

I thought this query would do it:

```
SELECT person, MIN(score) FROM golf_scores GROUP BY person ORDER BY score LIMIT 3;
```

but I get the following error:

> ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'records.golf_scores.score' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Adding `score` to the `GROUP BY` list just returns the lowest 3 scores total, regardless of duplicates in the `person` column.

***How can I get the desired output in MySQL?***

Comment: _Avoid answering questions in comments._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since order by clause is executed after select clause,try putting an aliases for min(score) .

`SELECT person, MIN(score) as min_score FROM golf_scores GROUP BY person ORDER BY min_score LIMIT 3;`

Comment: Thanks for answering this!  Unfortunately, I my MWE was a little too simple, because in the real table I have other columns in the rows as well.  Could you take a look at this [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54710377/1717828) I opened and see if you can help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `row_number()`

```
    select * from
    (
         SELECT person, score,row_number() over(partition by person order by score) as rn
         FROM golf_scores 
    )A where rn=1
    ORDER BY score LIMIT 3
```