# Show top N rows by category in MySQL 8 without duplicates in another category

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct, mysql-8.0

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54702226/1717828), I have the following table in MySQL 8.0.15:

```
CREATE TABLE golf_scores (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, person TEXT, score INT, age INT);
INSERT INTO golf_scores (person, score, age) VALUES ('Angela', 40, 25),('Angela', 45, 25),('Angela', 55, 25),('Peter',45, 32),('Peter',55,32),('Rachel', 65, 35),('Rachel',75,35),('Jeff',75, 16);
SELECT * FROM golf_scores;
+----+--------+-------+------+
| id | person | score | age  |
+----+--------+-------+------+
|  1 | Angela |    40 |   25 |
|  2 | Angela |    45 |   25 |
|  3 | Angela |    55 |   25 |
|  4 | Peter  |    45 |   32 |
|  5 | Peter  |    55 |   32 |
|  6 | Rachel |    65 |   35 |
|  7 | Rachel |    75 |   35 |
|  8 | Jeff   |    75 |   16 |
+----+--------+-------+------+
```

We want to select the following "best" 3 rows:

```
+----+--------+-------+------+
| id | person | score | age  |
+----+--------+-------+------+
|  1 | Angela |    40 |   25 |
|  4 | Peter  |    45 |   32 |
|  6 | Rachel |    65 |   35 |
+----+--------+-------+------+
```

In other words, the lowest 3 golf scores without having duplicates by person, **and also the other columns from that row**. I'm not worried about ties; I'd still just like three results.

The query `SELECT person, MIN(score) as min_score FROM golf_scores GROUP BY person ORDER BY min_score LIMIT 3;` gives the right rows, but is limited to the columns `person` and score`.  When I try to modify it like this:

```
SELECT id, person, MIN(score) as min_score, age FROM golf_scores GROUP BY person ORDER BY min_score LIMIT 3;
```

I get this error:

> ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'records.golf_scores.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I also tried eliminating duplicate names with `SELECT id, DISTINCT person, score, age FROM golf_scores ORDER BY score LIMIT 3` but I get an error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT person, score FROM golf_scores ORDER BY score LIMIT 3' at line 1

***How can I get the desired output in MySQL?***

Comment: *Avoid answering questions in comments.*

Comment: MySQL version 8 has window functions!

Comment: Why is a person's age stored next to score?

Comment: And why not person_id instead of person name.

Comment: @SalmanA, It's an MWE meant to represent a real app that I didn't do the best job reducing.  Maybe a column like `temperature` would have been better, since that's a feature of the golf round and not the person.  Either way, it's just one table and we're looking to return all the rows in it.  Thanks for pointing that out, though!

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by person order by score) as seqnum
      from golf_scores  t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
order by score asc
limit 3;
```

In older versions, you can do this by using a correlated subquery and `id`:

```
select gs.*
from golf_scores gs
where gs.id = (select gs2.id
               from golf_scores gs2
               where gs2.person = gs.person
               order by gs2.score asc
               limit 1
              )
order by score asc
limit 3;
```

This may also be the fastest way with an index on `golf_scores(person, score, id)`.

Comment: Am I doing something wrong or does there need to be a `LIMIT 3` at the end to cut it off at the first 3 scores?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM golf_scores x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MIN(id) id FROM
            ( SELECT a.* 
                FROM golf_scores a 
                JOIN 
                   ( SELECT person, MIN(score) score FROM golf_scores GROUP BY person ) b 
                  ON b.person = a.person 
                 AND b.score = a.score 
            ) n
        GROUP
           BY person
            , score 
     ) y
    ON y.id = x.id
 ORDER 
    BY x.score LIMIT 3;
```